# Displaying APNS push notification with Unicode on iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to trigger an APNS push notification. Its format is like `Username triggered a message`, and `username` might be in any language, including right-to-left languages.

It works fine except in the case in which username is in Urdu or any language which we read right to left. We checked the message on iOS via debugging tools and the message sent from server seems to have arrived correctly. However, when displaying the message on the screen, we see "triggered a message Username"

How can we display mixed-direction text?

Comment: Hello, did you ever solve this?  I'm currently investigating the same issue.